# Blaze error: No disk in drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, launcher

Running Blaze on Win 7 64-bit PC and getting the following error: There is not disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive\Device\Harddisk2\DR2. View error message here: http://screencast.com/t/ZjQxNDc0NW. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the indexer that's having trouble. Can you check that it isn't trying to index a drive that doesn't exist?

Comment: Actually I disabled the setting ... "Monitor my activity," and I have not had the error in a while. All the drives being indexed seem to be OK. Here is the setting I changed: http://screencast.com/t/YmY5ZDM5Y, and here is a shot of the drives being indexed. Please let me know if you see anything amiss: http://screencast.com/t/ZTMwM2M3Mj. Thanks. jeff@jeffruday.com.

Comment: Looks like it should be fine. You disabled "Monitor my activity" and error message stops? I don't really use Blaze, so can't help much. Uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Error came back but less frequently. Do you think this could have anything to do with my use of TrueCrypt?

Comment: It's possible. Any connection between error and encrypted folders/drives? Might be something in either Blaze or TrueCrypt faqs or forums?